# User roles propagation from Spring Security web tier to the EJB tier

Tags: spring, glassfish, ejb

I have a question. I don't exactly understand, how is the list of roles of an user propageated from web tier using Spring Security to EJB. Here is my research.

I have written down this in Spring application context:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="jimi" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:user name="bob" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

After login I open the page, where I have two tests of user's role. One is situated in web tier

```
<p>User is in role <code>ROLE_ADMIN</code>: <code>#{request.isUserInRole('ROLE_ADMIN')}</code></p>
```

and the second in the EJB tier:

```
@Resource
SessionContext ctx;

@Override
public String getString() {
    return "Authorized user: " + ctx.getCallerPrincipal() + ", admin=" + ctx.isCallerInRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
}
```

But result is inconsistent:

```
Authorized user: jimi, admin=false
User is in role ROLE_ADMIN: true
```

I tought I needed to add the user `jimi` into one of realms. But now, when I have created the user `jimi` with role `ROLE_ADIM` in file realm, I get the same result. The user name is propagated, but role list isn't. I'm reading manuals, but I don't now, what I'm exactly looking for.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Are you realy using EJB? And if yes, how are the both systems: frontent and EJB-Tier are connected?

Comment: The application constist of two layers. The data layer is implemented and deployed as EJB module. Presentation layer (web layer) is packaged and deployed separately as WAR. The controller in web tier uses JNDI lookup to get the bean. It works except user roles propagation.